# Activate Site Publishing Features via Powershell for SharePoint 2010 throws exception

Tags: powershell, publishing-site

We are having trouble activating the Publishing Site Features via Powershell.  The 2 features we are trying to activate are:

- PublishingSite
- PublishingWeb

We are executing the following Powershell:

```
$featPubSite = Get-SPFeature | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq "PublishingSite"}
Enable-SPFeature -Identity $featPubSite -Url "http://mysite"

$featPubWeb = Get-SPFeature | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq "PublishingWeb"}
Enable-SPFeature -Identity $featPubWeb -Url "http://mysite"
```

The following is from the SP Logs (NOTE I have removed the time and process which is all powershell.exe).

```
Fields                          e8gd    High        Exception thrown while fetching field by internal name 'Wiki_x0020_Page_x0020_Categories' System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\SP_Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\vtavq1t5.dll'.  File name: 'C:\Users\SP_Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\vtavq1t5.dll'     at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)     at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)     at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Fi... 58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
Fields                          e8gd    High        ...leOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)     at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)     at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames)     at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)     at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)     at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)     at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)     at System....  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
Fields                          e8gd    High        ...Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)     at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace)     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSimpleItem.DeserializeXmlData(String xmlData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPField.get_CustomProperties()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPField.GetCustomProperty(String propertyName)     at ...  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
Fields                          e8gd    High        ...Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.SetProperties()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.Initialize(SPFieldCollection fields)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField..ctor(SPFieldCollection fields, String fieldName)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeConstructor(Object[] args, SignatureStruct& signature, IntPtr declaringType)     at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)     at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.CreateSPFieldFromSafeArray(Int32 index)     at Mic...  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
Fields                          e8gd    High        ...rosoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.CreateSPField(Int32 ifld)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.EnsureSPField(Int32 index)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.GetFieldByInternalName(String strName, Boolean bThrowException) 58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
Feature Infrastructure          88jm    High        Feature receiver assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c', class 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.EnterpriseWikiSiteFeatureHandler', method 'FeatureActivated' for feature 'a942a218-fa43-4d11-9d85-c01e3e3a37cb' threw an exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\SP_Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\vtavq1t5.dll'.  File name: 'C:\Users\SP_Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\vtavq1t5.dll'     at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)     at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferS... 58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
Feature Infrastructure          88jm    High        ...ize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)     at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)     at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)     at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames)     at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)     at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)     at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFrom...  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
Feature Infrastructure          88jm    High        ...Source(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)     at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)     at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)     at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace)     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)     at ...  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
Feature Infrastructure          88jm    High        ...Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSimpleItem.DeserializeXmlData(String xmlData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPField.get_CustomProperties()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPField.GetCustomProperty(String propertyName)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.SetProperties()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.Initialize(SPFieldCollection fields)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField..ctor(SPFieldCollection fields, String fieldName)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeConstructor(Object[] args, SignatureStruct& signature, IntPtr declaringType)     at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)     at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanc...  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
Feature Infrastructure          88jm    High        ...eImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.CreateSPFieldFromSafeArray(Int32 index)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.CreateSPField(Int32 ifld)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.EnsureSPField(Int32 index)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.GetFieldByInternalName(String strName, Boolean bThrowException)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.EnterpriseWikiSiteFeatureHandler.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.DoActivationCallout(Boolean fActivate, Boolean fForce) 58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
General                         72by    High        Feature Activation: Threw an exception, attempting to roll back.  Feature 'EnterpriseWikiLayouts' (ID: 'a942a218-fa43-4d11-9d85-c01e3e3a37cb').  Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\SP_Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\vtavq1t5.dll'.  File name: 'C:\Users\SP_Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\vtavq1t5.dll'     at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)     at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)     at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileM... 58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
General                         72by    High        ...ode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)     at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)     at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames)     at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)     at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)     at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)     at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerC...  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
General                         72by    High        ...ompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)     at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)     at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace)     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSimpleItem.DeserializeXmlData(String xmlData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPField.get_CustomProperties()     at Microsoft...  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
General                         72by    High        ....SharePoint.SPField.GetCustomProperty(String propertyName)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.SetProperties()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.Initialize(SPFieldCollection fields)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField..ctor(SPFieldCollection fields, String fieldName)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeConstructor(Object[] args, SignatureStruct& signature, IntPtr declaringType)     at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)     at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SP...  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
General                         72by    High        ...FieldCollection.CreateSPFieldFromSafeArray(Int32 index)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.CreateSPField(Int32 ifld)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.EnsureSPField(Int32 index)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.GetFieldByInternalName(String strName, Boolean bThrowException)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.EnterpriseWikiSiteFeatureHandler.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.DoActivationCallout(Boolean fActivate, Boolean fForce)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, Boolean fForce)   58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (Feature Activation: Activating Feature 'EnterpriseWikiLayouts' (ID: 'a942a218-fa43-4d11-9d85-c01e3e3a37cb') at URL http://mysite.). Execution Time=514.283168  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
General                         8grz    High        The feature 'f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa' depends on feature 'a942a218-fa43-4d11-9d85-c01e3e3a37cb' which failed to activate: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\SP_Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\vtavq1t5.dll'.  File name: 'C:\Users\SP_Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\vtavq1t5.dll'     at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)     at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)     at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess ... 58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
General                         8grz    High        ...access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)     at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)     at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames)     at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)     at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)     at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)     at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xml...  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
General                         8grz    High        ...Parameters, Evidence evidence)     at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)     at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace)     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSimpleItem.DeserializeXmlData(String xmlData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPField.get_CustomProperties()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPField.G...  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
General                         8grz    High        ...etCustomProperty(String propertyName)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.SetProperties()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.Initialize(SPFieldCollection fields)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField..ctor(SPFieldCollection fields, String fieldName)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeConstructor(Object[] args, SignatureStruct& signature, IntPtr declaringType)     at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)     at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.Creat...  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
General                         8grz    High        ...eSPFieldFromSafeArray(Int32 index)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.CreateSPField(Int32 ifld)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.EnsureSPField(Int32 index)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.GetFieldByInternalName(String strName, Boolean bThrowException)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.EnterpriseWikiSiteFeatureHandler.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.DoActivationCallout(Boolean fActivate, Boolean fForce)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, Boolean fForce)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, Boolean ...  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
General                         8grz    High        ...force, Boolean fMarkOnly)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.CheckSameScopeDependency(SPFeatureDefinition featdefDependant, SPFeatureDependency featdep, SPFeatureDefinition featdefDependency, Boolean fActivateHidden, Boolean fUpgrade, Boolean fForce, Boolean fMarkOnly)   58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
General                         75fg    High        Exception was thrown while ensuring dependencies met for feature 'PublishingSite' (id: f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa): System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\SP_Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\vtavq1t5.dll'.  File name: 'C:\Users\SP_Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\vtavq1t5.dll'     at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)     at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)     at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, F... 58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
General                         75fg    High        ...ileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)     at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)     at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames)     at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)     at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)     at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)     at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameter...  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
General                         75fg    High        ...s, Evidence evidence)     at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)     at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace)     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSimpleItem.DeserializeXmlData(String xmlData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPField.get_CustomProperties()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPField.GetCustomP...  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
General                         75fg    High        ...roperty(String propertyName)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.SetProperties()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.Initialize(SPFieldCollection fields)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField..ctor(SPFieldCollection fields, String fieldName)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeConstructor(Object[] args, SignatureStruct& signature, IntPtr declaringType)     at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)     at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.CreateSPFieldF...  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
General                         75fg    High        ...romSafeArray(Int32 index)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.CreateSPField(Int32 ifld)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.EnsureSPField(Int32 index)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.GetFieldByInternalName(String strName, Boolean bThrowException)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.EnterpriseWikiSiteFeatureHandler.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.DoActivationCallout(Boolean fActivate, Boolean fForce)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, Boolean fForce)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, Boolean force, Bo...  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
General                         75fg    High        ...olean fMarkOnly)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.CheckSameScopeDependency(SPFeatureDefinition featdefDependant, SPFeatureDependency featdep, SPFeatureDefinition featdefDependency, Boolean fActivateHidden, Boolean fUpgrade, Boolean fForce, Boolean fMarkOnly)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.CheckFeatureDependency(SPFeatureDefinition featdefDependant, SPFeatureDependency featdep, Boolean fActivateHidden, Boolean fUpgrade, Boolean fForce, Boolean fMarkOnly, FailureReason& errType)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.CheckFeatureDependencies(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Boolean fActivateHidden, Boolean fUpgrade, Boolean fForce, Boolean fThrowError, Boolean fMarkOnly, List`1& missingFeatures)  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
Feature Infrastructure          8e0j    High        Feature Activation: Failed to ensure feature dependencies for feature 'PublishingSite' (id: 'f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa'), exception thrown: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\SP_Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\vtavq1t5.dll'.  File name: 'C:\Users\SP_Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\vtavq1t5.dll'     at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)     at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)     at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode m... 58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
Feature Infrastructure          8e0j    High        ...ode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)     at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)     at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames)     at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)     at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)     at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)     at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompil...  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
Feature Infrastructure          8e0j    High        ...erParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)     at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)     at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace)     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSimpleItem.DeserializeXmlData(String xmlData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPField.get_CustomProperties()     at Microsoft.Shar...  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
Feature Infrastructure          8e0j    High        ...ePoint.SPField.GetCustomProperty(String propertyName)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.SetProperties()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.Initialize(SPFieldCollection fields)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField..ctor(SPFieldCollection fields, String fieldName)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeConstructor(Object[] args, SignatureStruct& signature, IntPtr declaringType)     at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)     at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPField...  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
Feature Infrastructure          8e0j    High        ...Collection.CreateSPFieldFromSafeArray(Int32 index)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.CreateSPField(Int32 ifld)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.EnsureSPField(Int32 index)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.GetFieldByInternalName(String strName, Boolean bThrowException)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.EnterpriseWikiSiteFeatureHandler.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.DoActivationCallout(Boolean fActivate, Boolean fForce)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, Boolean fForce)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection prop...  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
Feature Infrastructure          8e0j    High        ...erties, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.CheckSameScopeDependency(SPFeatureDefinition featdefDependant, SPFeatureDependency featdep, SPFeatureDefinition featdefDependency, Boolean fActivateHidden, Boolean fUpgrade, Boolean fForce, Boolean fMarkOnly)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.CheckFeatureDependency(SPFeatureDefinition featdefDependant, SPFeatureDependency featdep, Boolean fActivateHidden, Boolean fUpgrade, Boolean fForce, Boolean fMarkOnly, FailureReason& errType)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.CheckFeatureDependencies(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Boolean fActivateHidden, Boolean fUpgrade, Boolean fForce, Boolean fThrowError, Boolean fMarkOnly, List`1& missingFeatures)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatu...  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
Feature Infrastructure          8e0j    High        ...reCollection.CheckFeatureDependencies(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Boolean fActivateHidden, Boolean fUpgrade, Boolean fForce, Boolean fMarkOnly)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly) 58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
PowerShell                      6tf2    High        Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.   58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
PowerShell                      91ux    High        Error Category: InvalidData    Target Object  Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletEnableFeature  Details  NULL  RecommendedAction NULL  58c54acc-123a-45dc-a326-d1760e26965a
```

Now the same Powershell commands work fine on our other servers.  There is one server that is causing trouble.  We can activate the SharePoint Server Publishing Infastructure Feature from the Site Collection Features in the web front end and also the SharePoint Server Publishing Feature from the Site Features.